# Java - Why is it necesary to use Class class's instance methods write classname.class.method or instance.getClass().method?

Tags: java, class, methods

Why is it necesary to use Class class's methods to write classname.class.method or instance.getClass().method?

For example:

```
public class SomeClass{
   public static void main (String[] args){
       SomeClass sm = new SomeClass();
       //The correct ways:
       System.out.println(sm.getClass().getName());
       //or
       System.out.println(SomeClass.class.getName()); 
   }
}
```

Class class's instance methods need a class (it can be seen when in `System.out.println(sm.getClass().getName();` because sm.getClass() returns a class) so why is not correct to write `System.out.println(SomeClass.getName();` and it is necessary to write "class" in the middle if getName() method is called by a class? Is it because SomeClass class is not considered an instance of Class class? Why sm.getClass() is considered an instance of Class class then?

Thank you.

Comment: " Is it because SomeClass class is not considered an instance of Class ". Yes.

Comment: The word "class" no longer has meaning.

Comment: Because these are methods of class `java.lang.Class`, and just like any other method, you must call them on an object of the appropriate type (in this case, a `Class` object). And arbitrary objects are not instances of their corresponding `Class` object. All objects are subtypes of `java.lang.Object`, but not of `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: You are talking about the `Class class`. The class named `Class` offers information about classes at runtime. There are basically two ways to get a `Class` object: Either you ask any object, what class it is, by calling `getClass()` on it. Since this method is defined in `Object`, every class has it. The other way is to get a specific Class object, by writing, for example, `String.class`. So, you use `getClass()` when you want to dynamically get the `Class` object of a random object and `.class` if you want a specific `Class` object.

Answer (score 4):

`new SomeClass()` creates an instance of the `SomeClass` class :

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
```

It doesn't provide the `Class` instance of `SomeClass` as the `getClass()` instance method of `Object` class does :

```
Class<? extends SomeClass> clazz = new SomeClass().getClass();
```

These are two totally different things.

Comment: Isn't `new SC().getClass()` a `Class<? extends SC>`, rather than a `Class<SC>`?

Comment: Of course, you could have just gone with `Class<SC> clazz = SC.class;`.

Comment: I know. I mixed two usages ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it necesary to use Class class's methods to write classname.class.method or instance.getClass().method?

Java has no free-standing functions, so in order to invoke any function, you have to invoke it as a member of a class.  And if you want to invoke a function that belongs to class A, you have to invoke it as a method of class A.  I know this is a tautology; but this is what your question, as stated, calls for.

> why is not correct to write System.out.println(SomeClass().getName();

It is not correct to write that, because it is not valid java syntax.  Java reserves the class-name-followed-by-parentheses construct to stand for identifying constructors.  (And it must be prefixed by `new`.)

> it is necessary to write "class" in the middle if getName() method is called by a class?

Besides not supporting free-standing functions, java does not support any free-standing code whatsoever, so in order to call anything, the calling code must be in a class, so all methods are called by a class.

> Is it because SomeClass class is not considered an instance of Class class?

Uhm, yes.

> Why sm.getClass() is considered an instance of Class class then?

It is not considered an instance of a class.  But it does return an instance of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I am breaking the line to understand the easy way.Hope so it will be helpful

```
SomeClass sm = new SomeClass();

Class clazz1 = sm.getClass(); //sm.getClass() returns Class object
System.out.println(clazz1.getName());    

Class clazz2 = SomeClass.class; //SomeClass.class returns Class object 

System.out.println(clazz2.getName());
```

That means getName() method is available in Class class .